# Swipe gestures in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

So I have a `WKWebView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. I have to open few webpages but those webpages are eating up the scrolling by overriding `touchmove` event as below:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I have tried adding swipe gestures to `WKWebView` and its `superview`. `touchesMoved:` is also not getting called inside superview. I cant disable `userInteraction` on webview as I want to be able to tap and interact with webview.

I tried overriding the existing `touchmove` event of webpage by injecting script:

```
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc]initWithSource:@"window.ontouchmove = function() { \
                            window.webkit.messageHandlers.touchmoved.postMessage('Touches Moved..'); \
                                return true; \
                            };" injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:NO];

    WKUserScript *docscript = [[WKUserScript alloc]initWithSource:@"document.ontouchmove = function() { \
                            window.webkit.messageHandlers.touchmoved.postMessage('Doc Touches Moved..'); \
                            return true; \
                            };" injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:NO];
    [config.userContentController addUserScript:script];
    [config.userContentController addUserScript:docscript];
    [config.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"touchmoved"];
```

I was getting callback in `didReceiveScriptMessage` but it dint enable scrolling.

Is there any way to enable scrolling or to add swipe gestures for such webpages?